# scrollLeft attribute gives a value less than expected

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html element:

```
<div id="main_track" onscroll="update_current_position(this)" height=50 
style="width:901px;margin: auto;overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: hidden;position: relative; " >
        <canvas height=50 style="width:901px;" id='timeLine'></canvas>
    </div>
<br><p style="margin-top: 0;">current position: <a id="current_pos"></a> ms</p>
```

and the following javascript function:

```
function update_current_position(track){
    var time = track.scrollLeft;
    time=time*10;
    document.getElementById("current_pos").innerHTML=time.toString();
}
```

The canavas element width is editable by another input element.

I set the width of the canavas to something wider than the div, then I scroll the div and I find the function not giving the right out put. for example: if the scollLeft is 10 , the function returns 9.600001564.
I tried to change the scroll from the browser console and it gives the same result.

[image]

When I scroll by mouse I get many floats in current_pos element, but scrollLeft is supposed to be an integer.
[image]
I need an accurate detection of scroll, where every pixel represents 10 ms, how can I fix that?
EDIT: I tried that on firefox and it worked fine, seems to be a problem with chrome.

Comment: Someone reported the bug: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/4220583?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and find its working fine as you can check below code of mine,
I just increase canvas width by 1 px and after scrolling, we got 10 ms as expected

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> testing </title>
</head>
<body style="width:100%">
    <h1>Hello there</h1>
    <div id="main_track" onscroll="update_current_position(this)" height=50 
    style="width:901px;margin: auto;overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: hidden; border:1px solid black;position: relative; " >
            <canvas height=50 style="width:902px;" id='timeLine'></canvas>
        </div>
    <br><p style="margin-top: 0;">current position: <a id="current_pos"></a> ms</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function update_current_position(track){
            var time = track.scrollLeft; 
            time=time*10;
            document.getElementById("current_pos").innerHTML=time.toString();
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

check below screenshot also

[image: Screen shot of above code in working]

Comment: Yes, when you change the scroll by mouse to the end it works, but what about changing it from javascript code? try making the width of the canavas to 1401 pixels (in this case, the scroll end is 5000 ms position), then change the scrollLeft from console to 10, is it working fine?

Comment: let me check that case also

Comment: when I make the width of the canavas 1401 pixels and scroll by mouse I see many floats in current_pos element, but scrollLeft is supposed to be an integer.

Comment: No, I haven't found what you said, I tried everything you said, 
Please let me know which browser you're using ?

Comment: Google chrome on windows 10 and edge on windows 10,
It worked as expected in Firefox.

Comment: I'm also using chrome but on Linux,
Have your chrome is up to date?
Please check the version of your chrome browser.

Comment: I updated chrome and the problem is persistent, I used Math.round(time) before multiplying by 10 to avoid that bug anyway.

Comment: I uploaded an image showing float in current_pos element

Comment: someone reported the same bug, it seems to be in chrome for windows only. Thank you for your interest. https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/4220583?hl=en